# Ethernet Connection Keeps Disconnecting and Reconnecting

Tags: 16.04, ethernet, realtek

I find my Ethernet connection keeps disconnecting then reconnecting. I'm on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Here is the response from

```
lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:2a92]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt install rtl8168-dkms` and reboot. You will also need to disable Secure Boot if you have UEFI.

Comment: I get an error saying "E: Unable to locate package rtl8168-dkms". Any advice? I'm also using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @Mav14 maybe the package you need is rtl8812au-dkms?  It is the only one I find in "Synaptic" when searching for rtl.

Comment: @Mav14 On Ubuntu 16.04 the package is called r8168-dkms.